# Use awk to check a specific combination in other files

Tags: string, shell, awk, exists

I have 3 files

base.txt

```
12345 6 78
13579 2 46
24680 1 35
123451 266 78
135792 6572 46
246803 12587 35
```

1stcheck.txt

```
Some odded stuffs
AB 12345/6/78 Fx00
BC 13579/2/47 0xFF
CD 24680/1/35 5x88
AB 123451/266_10/78 Fx00  #10 is mod(266,256)
BC 135792/6572_172/46 0xFF #172 is mod(6572,256)
CD 246803/12587_43/35 5x88 #43 is mod(12587,256)
There may be some other odded stuffs
```

2ndcheck.txt

```
12345u_6_78.dat
13579u_2_46.dat
24680u_0_35.dat
123451u_10_78.dat #10 is mod(266,256)
135792u_172_46.dat #172 is mod(6572,256)
246803u_43_35.dat #43 is mod(12587,256)
```

The info in 1stcheck.txt and 2ndcheck.txt is just combination of base.txt in applied some template/format

I'd like to have

report.txt

```
12345 6 78  passed           passed
              |                |
        (12345/6/78)      (12345u_6_78)
13579 2 46  failed           passed  
24680 1 35  passed           failed
123451 266 78     passed           passed           
135792 6572 46    passed           passed           
246803 12587 35   passed           passed
```

Please help to consider about performance since

- base.txt,2ndcheck.txt ~ 8MB-12MB
- 1stcheck.txt ~ 70MB

Many thanks

Comment: `passed/failed` logic is not clear. What have you tried?

Comment: passed is if the 3 fields are the same in the check file as in the base file. first failed is because the third field became 47 and second fail is because the second field became 0. I would parse the first file with result as failed and set result to passed if the formatted fields are present in the result files... (awk with internal call to grep maybe ?)

Comment: Do all the elements in "base" appear in the two "check" files? Is there a one-to-one correspondence between "base" and "2ndcheck"?

Comment: The element in "base" doesnot have to display in the two "check" files. No 1-on-1 correspondence between base and both 2 "check"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to decide if this is memory efficient: it does have to store data from all files in arrays before printing the table.

Required GNU awk

```
gawk '
  # base file: store keys (and line numbers for output ordering)
  FILENAME == ARGV[1] {key[$0] = FNR; next} 

  # 1st check: if key appears in base, store result as pass
  FILENAME == ARGV[2] {
    k = $2
    gsub(/\//, " ", k)
    if (k in key) pass1[k] = 1
  }

  # 2nd check: if key appears in base, store result as pass
  FILENAME == ARGV[3] {
    if ( match($0, /([0-9]+)._([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)\.dat/, m) ) {
      k = m[1] " " m[2] " " m[3]
      if (k in key) pass2[k] = 1
    }
    next
  }

  # print the result table
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"   # traverse array by line number
    for (k in key) {
      printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", k \
                           , (k in pass1 ? "passed" : "failed") \
                           , (k in pass2 ? "passed" : "failed")
    }
  }
' base.txt 1stcheck.txt 2ndcheck.txt
```

```
12345 6 78  passed  passed
13579 2 46  failed  passed
24680 1 35  passed  failed
```

Comment: I'd like to thank you one more time. The performance is very good, I did proceed base:1MB, 1stcheck:80MB, 2ndcheck:60MB and it only takes me 30s to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @glenn jackman's suggestion, I could solve my problem

```
gawk '
  # Store key for 1st check
  FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    k = $2
    gsub(/\//, " ", k)  
    key_first[k];next    
  }

  # Store key for 2nd check
  FILENAME == ARGV[2] {
    if ( match($0, /([0-9]+)._([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)\.dat/, m) ) {
      k = m[1] " " m[2] " " m[3]      
      key_second[k];
    }
    next
  }

  # base file: do check on both 1st and 2nd check
  FILENAME == ARGV[3] {
    if($2>256) {
        first=$1 " " $2 "_" ($2%256) " " $3 
    }
    else {
        first=$1 " " $2 " " $3 
    } 
    second=$1 " " $2%256 " " $3         
    if (first in key_first) pass1[$0] = 1
    if (second in key_second) pass2[$0] = 1 
    key[$0]= FNR;   next
  } 

  # print the result table
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"   # traverse array by line number
    for (k in key) {
      printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", k \
                           , (k in pass1 ? "sic_passed" : "sic_failed") \
                           , (k in pass2 ? "gd_passed" : "gd_failed")
    }
  }
' 1stcheck.txt 2ndcheck.txt base.txt
```